# Cambiar tablas de AspNetUsers a Users en asp.net core 2.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, configuración, .net-core

Soy nuevo en Asp.net core 2.x, así que ...

Me gustaría cambiar las tablas de autenticación de `AspNetUsers` a `Users` en **asp.net core 2.2**.

Intente hacerlo en la migración que vino por defecto, pero al registrarme me dice que la tabla `AspNetUsers` no existe, aunque en la migración y en la base cambie la tabla a `Users`

Comment: Hola, lo hiciste directamente en la base de datos, o modificaste la migración inicial de EntityFramework?.

Comment: lo hice en la migracion "CreateIdentitySchema : Migration". Cuando modifique toda la migracion le di Update-database, me creo las tablas sin el AspNet pero a la hora de registrar el usuario me salto que no existia la tabla AspNetUsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una forma de sustituir el prefijo '**AspNet**' de la tablas de "autenticación", con **EntityFramework Core**.

En tu **`DbContext`**, sobrescribe el método `OnModelCreating()` de la siguiente manera:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

  foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
  {
      var table = entityType.Relational().TableName;
      if (table.StartsWith("AspNet")) 
      {
         entityType.Relational().TableName = table.Substring(6);
      }
  };
}
```

Esto hará que a todas las tablas que comiencen por '**AspNet**', se les elimine este prefijo a la hora de crearlas.
Para tu caso esta solución hará que las nomenclaturas de tu base de datos queden más homogéneas.

Comment: Solo sobreescribo ese metodo y correo la migracion como esta o las vuelvo a crear.

Comment: Hola, debes volver a crear las tablas. Crea una nueva migración y mira a ver que te genera EF Core.

Comment: Listo ya me salio, te lo agradesco.

Comment: Una consulta, como puedo hacer para que el Login salga al momento de levantar el App y se manege la sesion cuando se acabe me bote y me direccione al login

Comment: @BryanIbarra: Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta. En cuanto a tu consulta, te recomiendo abras una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Te agradesco intente valorar pero aun soy reputacion 3, al parecer no se me muestra la valoracion. la tendre presenta muchas gracias.